# mysql query returns wrong for grouped data

Tags: php, mysql, sql

This is mysql table called matches. It contain matches that user bets on, date when they published it and result (win,lost etc..).

[image: http://imgur.com/Umt5Q4m]

With this 1st query i display on user profile his bets  grouped by months

```
SELECT COUNT(*),date,SUM(stake), AVG(stake),result 
FROM matches 
WHERE u_id='$id11' 
GROUP BY DATE_FORMAT(date, '%Y/%m') 
ORDER BY DATE_FORMAT(date, '%Y/%m') DESC 
LIMIT $startrow,10
```

Now what i need to do is to display how much of these bets were won , how much were lost , as u can see in the photo below

[image: http://imgur.com/kSOF6Pi]

What is the best way to do it ?

I already tryed to add another query witch looks like this

```
SELECT COUNT(*) 
FROM matches WHERE u_id='$id11' AND result='win' 
GROUP BY DATE_FORMAT(date, '%Y/%m') 
ORDER BY DATE_FORMAT(date, '%Y/%m') DESC LIMIT $startrow,10
```

and same query for every result ,but the problem is lats say there are no lost bets in this month its not returning anything for this month and than table looks in wrong order.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

How about to get all win/lost in one query,your where filter is filtering the results therefore you don't get the results for the query to get lost matches

```
SELECT 
 SUM(result='win') `win_count`,
 SUM(result='lost') `lost_count`
FROM matches 
WHERE u_id='$id11'  
GROUP BY DATE_FORMAT(date, '%Y/%m') 
ORDER BY DATE_FORMAT(date, '%Y/%m')
DESC LIMIT $startrow,10
```

In above query i have used `SUM` function with an expression,when expression is used in `SUM` it will result in a boolean and gives 1 for expression is true and 0 if expression results as false,in other words you can simply get the count through sum function by using your conditions

Comment: U are amazing , such simple solution. Thank u very much.